# How was this beautiful textbook created? Where's the stylesheet?

Tags: stylesheet, cdf-format, document-creation

**UPDATE:
The video presentation on how this was carried out by the author is given at the following link:** http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?c=88&v=185

---

I am really impressed by the way this textbook was created. This is so much more than just a textbook, I would like to create class notes type CDF document in this very style.

[Mathematica CDF Textbook example](http://www.wolfram.com/cdf/uses-examples/textbooks.html)

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

***How can I create something like this, is there a stylesheet I can use?***

Comment: Take a look at Erik Schulz presentation at https://www.wolfram.com/events/technology-conference/2011/electronic-publishing.html

Comment: @GustavoDelfino, reading your reference, it became clear to me why the technology was not widely used :-))

Comment: Yes use the link mentioned in my update, the one in comments by @GustavoDelfino is outdated.

Comment: I’ve created a palette that builds the notebooks that look and work like Eric’s including navigation.  I’ll share the code if you’re interested.

Comment: @MichaelMcCain Sure you should. It would help others as well.

Comment: Hi, not sure if the palette was posted somewhere?  Just reading this post now (Jan. 2018) but have a large project ahead of me to pull together notebooks into some form of working textbook.  Any palettes and advice would help with the process!

Comment: @MichaelMcCain Mike could you please share the code for the palette that builds the notebooks.